# Python convert string to timestamp

Tags: python, timestamp

In python im trying to generate a timestamp based on a string input:
The data

```
19/21/2016  12:29:07
```

First I tried:

```
import time
import datetime
s = "19/04/2016"
seconds = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%d/%m/%Y").timetuple())
print seconds
```

Which worked, than I tried (with same imports):

```
s = "19/04/2016 12:29:07"
seconds = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%d/%m/%Y %H:M:S").timetuple())
print seconds
```

But I get the following error:

ValueError: time data '19/04/2016  12:29:07' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %H:M:S'

> %H    Hour (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.
>   %M    Minute as a zero-padded decimal number.
>   %S    Second as a zero-padded decimal number.

Why is the input not valid when adding the %H:%M:%S ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the 24 hour clock. The format of the first string is different from the second in that the second has an impossible value for month - 21.

**Update**:

Each placeholder should have a preceeding `%`:

```
s = "19/04/2016 12:29:07"
format = "%d/%m/%Y  %H:%M:%S"
```

Comment: Updated the question you were right that was a typo though.